# How to split text by nodes in YQL using /text() XPath selector

Tags: xpath, yql

I'm trying to pull tweets from Twitter feed of some user:

```
select * from html 
where url='https://twitter.com/gvanrossum' and
      xpath="//*[@data-component-term='tweet']//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' ProfileTweet-text ')]/descendant-or-self::*//text()"
```

But results that I get is just one string with concatendated text of ALL tweets. How can I achieve result with separated tweets texts?

[Console link](http://goo.gl/BDqcq5)

### UPDATE #1

That is an example of how actual and expected results differ:
Actual result:

```
"text1 text2 text3"
```

Expected result:

```
[
  "text1",
  "text2",
  "text3"
]
```

Comment: Please show the output you expect (as far as I understand, inside a `results` element).

Comment: The XPath expression you have used _does_ return a set of nodes, but the environment (YQL?) you are using concatenates the results. Can you select the elements `xpath="//*[@data-component-term='tweet']//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' ProfileTweet-text ')]"` and extract the text afterwards?